# Touch events for Safari desktop templates on Dashcode for iPad

Tags: ipad, events, safari, touch, dashcode

Is there anyway to enable touch event handlers on the safari desktop templates? I want to use the Safari layout to make iPad apps since the mobile safari screen won't get any bigger than the iPhone width, but if I use the Safari desktop template to develop iPad apps I can't enable touch events. Does anyone have a good workaround or solution? Anything would help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have used [this example](http://rabblerule.blogspot.com/2009/08/detecting-swipe-in-webkit.html) to implement swipe events on an iphone web app to move through stacklayout views. It might work under the safari template to enable the touch events.